# Using while(true) statement a valid approach in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-2.0

In objective C, 
I am making my program to wait using while loop

```
doInitialize()
{
 dispach_group_t loadDataGroup=dispatch_group_create();
 dispatch_group_async(loadDataGroup,...get_global_queue(..),0),^{
   renewauth();
 }
 dispatch_group_notify(loadDataGroup,...get_global_queue(..),0),^{
   //Do other tasks once renew session has completed...
 }
}
renewauth()
{
 RenewAuthTokenInProgress=true;
 startRenewThread();
 **while (RenewAuthTokenInProgress);**
}
```

In turn startRenewThread() function also performs dispatch_async operation inside. So I have to make renewAuth() wait.

And async task in startRenewThread will update the bool variable once renewal is successful.

Is there any better approach of doing it other than dispatch_groups?
And is it good to make other threads wait with while (true) statement?

Comment: Busy waiting is a terrible idea. Why do you run this renewal function in the background if you want to block until it's done anyway?

Comment: And if you go the async route, what's wrong with `dispatch_groups`?

Comment: Assuming that RenewAuthTokenInProgress remains true for a while then yes your iPhone is going to get hot. You will be running one of the cores at 100%. It'll also flatten your battery.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar : Thats a very funny title to pretty good question :) Please consider modifying it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manoj Kumar,

using a while loop to wait till the boolean variable change is not the correct approach to solve the problem. Here are few of the issues with this method

1. Your CPU is un-necessarily burdened with checking the variable regularly.
2. This will clearly show that developer isn't much equipted with basic skills of coding and features available with language.
3. If for any reason your variable will never change then your CPU will never stop checking the value of bool in while loop and blocks the execution of further code on the same thread.

Here are few of the correct approach :

1. Blocks or closures : Make use of blocks to execute the code asynchronously when the RenewAuthToken is done.
2. Delegates : if blocks are harder to understand, Make use of delegates and trigger the delegate when you are done with RenewAuthToken.
3. Notifications : Add observer for notifications in classes which needs to respond when RenewAuthToken is done and throw notification from the asynctask and let the class to catch it execute the code.
4. Locks : If it is necessary to block the execution of the thread till the response comes use locks to control the thread execution rather than using while loop

**EDIT**

As pointed out by fogmeister in comments

> If you block the main thread for too long with a while(true) loop then
>   the app will actually be terminated by the iOS Watchdog as it will
>   assume it has crashed

Please have a look at the link : [understand iOS watchdog termination reasons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) provided by fogmeister

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also something to note. If you block the main thread for too long with a `while(true)` loop then the app will actually be terminated by the iOS Watchdog as it will assume it has crashed.

Comment: A link for you to add if you want https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html a search for `8badf00d` will show the watchdog termination reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Sandeep. I am not executing it in main thread. Even then my approach will burden the cpu right? And how to use blocks to introduce wait? I know how to use delegates and notifications. But not sure of how locks and blocks can be used here to introduce wait.

Comment: @manoj-kumar : Blocks will not introduce any wait buddy :) You can place the code which u want to execute once your RenewAuthToken webservice is successful and execute the block or closure when the RenewAuthToken is successful that way you will not block anythread and yet your code will be executed asynchronously only after the RenewAuthToken is completed :) Where as putting the locks like mutex locks will block that thread from executing because thread is not executing the burden on the cell will be reduced but not the correct approach always :) Locks are meant for specific cases

Comment: using them just to execute the code asynchronously is not the correct thing to do :) Please go through the blocks or closures tutorial to understand it better :) Still need help lemme know :)

Comment: Locks will prevent the thread from executing but won't introduce any wait here right? And can you give me some example of using notifications?

Comment: @manoj-kumar : When you apply a lock the code belonging to that thread will stop executing hence the wait :) But because thread is locked and paused its execution CPU is least botherred about it hence no pressure on CPU :) Simply search for locks in iOS you will find many tutiorials :) And as per blocks are concerned :) read https://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2 :) \

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need it's a `semaphore` like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
__block BOOL done = FALSE;
while (true) {

    [self someCompletionMethod completion:^(BOOL success) {

        if(success) { // Stop condition
            done = TRUE;
        }
        // do something
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem); // This will let a new iteration
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    if(done) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Dispatch to main
            NSLog(@"Done!");
            break;
        });
    }
}

});
```

> Semaphores are an old-school threading concept introduced to the world by the ever-so-humble Edsger W. Dijkstra. Semaphores are a complex topic because they build upon the intricacies of operating system functions.

You can see a tutorial here about semaphore and check it out more links: https://www.raywenderlich.com/63338/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-2

I hope this can help you.

Comment: No offense, but semaphores are often an alibi for laziness not to deal with the handling of asynchronous patterns.

Comment: No offence, but semaphores are often a beautiful way to handle asynchronous events. For this particular question, most likely not the right choice though. And an advanced technique, likely beyond the OP.

Comment: There is no offence, Thanks for both comments, I believe this is quite of opinion and I agree with gnasher729 but I really understood what you mean vadian.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is absolutely lethal. It blocks the running thread (presumably the main thread) so the UI is frozen. It runs one core at 100% load for no reason whatsoever which empties the battery rapidly and heats up the phone. This will get you some very, very unhappy customers or very, very happy ex-customers.

Anything like this has to run in the background: startRenewThread should trigger some action that sets RenewAuthTokenInProgress = NO and sets whether there is a new token or not, and then triggers further action.

This is an absolutely essential programming pattern on iOS (and Android as far as I know).